# Exception when trying to load .mp3 file in Phaser

Tags: dart, phaser-framework

I am trying to load a [very short .mp3 file](http://www.freesoundeffects.com/free-track/swordraw-426864/) in my `preload()` function like this:

```dart
game.load.audio('sword', '$assetPath/swordraw.mp3', true);
```

As soon as this code gets executed, it crashes with the error

```dart
Breaking on exception: Invalid arguments(s)
```

pointing to a `console.warn` in Phaser's `Loader`'s `fileError` function which is as below:

```dart
fileError(int index) {

  this._fileList[index]['loaded'] = true;
  this._fileList[index]['error'] = true;

  this.onFileError.dispatch([this._fileList[index]['key'], this._fileList[index]]);

  window.console.warn("Phaser.Loader error loading file: " 
  + this._fileList[index]['key'] + ' from URL ' + this._fileList[index]['url']);

    this.nextFile(index, false);

}
```

Through the debugger of DartEditor I have seen that for some reason `_fileList[10]['url']` (URL for audio file) is picked up as being null here, and that is the cause of the exception (can't concat. `null` to a string) but why is url null?

I've checked the obvious: the file name is correct and `assetPath` is certainly initialised correctly since all the other files (which are images) before this load fine. So this seems like an audio file issue of some kind but I can't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, seems like I found the offender here... https://github.com/playif/play_phaser/blob/ae6a08e5a6eb159149fac01e5831fd8572223a44/lib/loader/loader.dart#L1447

When the `Loader` is setting up stuff about a newly added file it calls this `getAudioUrl` if the file is an audio file...

```
getAudioURL(urls) {

//String extension;

if (urls is String) {
  urls = [urls];
}

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  var url = urls[i];
  //extension = urls[i].toLowerCase();
  //extension = extension.substr((Math.max(0, extension.lastIndexOf(".")) || Infinity) + 1);

  if (this.game.device.canPlayAudio(url.split('.').last)) {
    //return urls[i];
    return url;
  }

}

return null;
```

}

...and as you may gather from the above, the method will return `null` seemingly if the device cannot play the the type of file supplied. So then, Dartium can't play .mp3s?

Comment: I think playing mp3s requires licensed software which is shipped in chrome, but not in the open source chromium code base. Try running in chrome, or convert your audio to ogg vorbis.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. For now I found a [different site for sounds](http://www.bigsoundbank.com/) which seems to offer everything in a number of formats including .ogg :)